# Access servlet get method on button, without making form possible?

Tags: html

I have created an html file, which include 4 buttons. I want to access get/post method in my servlet "newOperator" from the second button.

So if you click on it, it should start the get method Automatic.

My code so far:

```
<br></br>

        <p align="center">

            <a href="Create.jsp" class="Button">Create new Operator</a><br>
        </p>

        <p align="center">

            <a action="newOperator" class="Button">Show Operators</a><br>
        </p>

        <p align="center">

            <a href="Create.jsp" class="Button">Update an Operator</a><br>
        </p>

        <p align="center">

            <a href="Create.jsp" class="Button">Delete an Operator</a><br>
        </p>
```

As you can see, the first button will open Create.jsp. This is working just fine, but if i want to run a get method in a servlet, how can this be done without making a form?

I tried it withs the forms, like:

```
<FORM METHOD="get" ACTION="newOperator">
        <INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Show all operators">
    </FORM>
```

this is working fine also, but then i can't get the same style i have created with CSS!

Hope someone got an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event handler to the button and write an ajax function that uses get to call your newOperator method.

Comment: Could you maybe explain it a Little better ); should the evant handler be placed in the servlet? or?

Comment: Sorry, that was a short answer.  I meant the event handler for the button itself so you can catch the click.  You could also just call your ajax function from the button by adding it directly, using the onclick="myajaxfunction()".  Are you using jQuery?  It would be easy to show a complete example then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change,

```
<p align="center">
    <a href="http://ip:port/contextPath/newOperator" class="Button">Show Operators</a><br>
</p>
```